# What is the locus of the points satisfying $|z-\alpha|/|z+\alpha| = c$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> What is the locus of the points $z\in\mathbb{C}$ satisfying
>   $$\left|\frac{z-\alpha}{z+\alpha}\right| = c,$$ where $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}, c\in\mathbb{R}$?

Plotting some examples by assigning values to $\alpha$ and $c$, I see that it is a conic section (it was a hyperbola in my example). But just writing $z = x+iy$ and $\alpha = a+ib$ the calculations get too long to carry and to organize in such a way that I could see what kind of curve it is in general. There is a "less painful" way to answer the question?

Comment: $c=\left|\frac{z-\alpha}{z+\alpha}\right|=\left|1-2\alpha \frac{1}{z+\alpha}\right|$ is the translation of $c=\left|1-2\alpha \frac{1}{z}\right|$, which is the inversion with respect to the unit circle of $c=\left|1-2\alpha z\right|$, which is a homothety and rotation with respect to the origin of the locus $c=\left|1-z\right|$, which is the translation of $c=\left|z\right|$, which is a circle with center $0$ and radius $c$. Since the transformations preserve circles in the extended plane, the original was a circle in the extended plane.

Answer (score 2):

$|z-\alpha|$= distance of $z$ from point $\alpha$
$|z+\alpha|$= distance of $z$ from point $-\alpha\quad(-\alpha $ is a point on opposite side of origin as $\alpha$)

So, we want locus of points whose distance from a point is some constant times the distance from another point.
 These loci can be easily found depending on the value of $c$ by definitions of conic sections.

Edit: It is actually either the perpendicular bisector of line joining $\alpha$ and $-\alpha$ ($c=1$) or the [circle of Apollonius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circles_of_Apollonius#Apollonius.27_definition_of_a_circle)

Answer (score 1):

with $z\neq-\alpha$ we have
\begin{align}
|z-\alpha| &= c|z+\alpha| \\
(z-\alpha)(\overline{z}-\overline{\alpha}) &= c^2(z+\alpha)(\overline{z}+\overline{\alpha}) \\
(1-c^2)|z|^2-2(1+c^2){\bf Re\,}\overline{\alpha}z+(1-c^2)|\alpha|^2 &= 0\\
|z|^2+|\alpha|^2-2\dfrac{1+c^2}{1-c^2}{\bf Re\,}\overline{\alpha}z &= 0
\end{align}
which is a circle.

Comment: It will be the perpendicular bisector of line joining $\alpha$ and $-\alpha$ if $c=1$

Comment: Yes. I must restrict it to $c^2\neq1$ has appear in denominator.

Comment: And you can assume $c \neq -1$ as it is the modulus of a complex number

Comment: But I saw a circle has the general form $az\overline{z} + bz + \overline{b}\overline{z} + c = 0$, and your expression doens't appear to have a term corresponding to $\overline{b}\overline{z}$.